# iOS app icons updated, not showing on clean Build/Run

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm prepping for my first update (1.0.1) on the AppStore and will be changing the icon in the process. I deleted the old 57x57 and 114x114 icons, dropped new ones into Xcode 4's target summary, and did a clean build/run. The new icons show up in Xcode, but not on the device's home screen.

I suspect if I delete the app and redo the above steps, this may work, but that leaves me to wonder if an AppStore distribution will update the icons for all users.

Is there something I'm forgetting to do to update the icon for this next release?

Comment: I also suspect this has something to do with the fact that the dev version overwrites the app store version on my phone (having the same bundle id) and the assets are not completely removed from the "purchased" copy I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that my new icons had slightly different names than the old. Strangely, Xcode never complained and still showed them next to the target and in the summary.

**Lesson learned:** When doing an app update (or "Appdate"), modified resources need to be of the same file name to be found. It seems replacing a resource with a different resource is not sufficient. Overwriting the old resource is the way  to go.

Answer (score 11):

I was having this problem when replacing icons for an app, the new icons didn't show up on the iOS device, no matter how many times I did a clean/build. The solution for me was to reboot the device and the new icons were recognized.

I'm guessing this is a problem only in development, it is likely that the cached icon is refreshed when an app is installed or updated from the App Store.

Comment: For me, the problem was solved when I rebooted the device. The new app icon showed up. Thanks @Kekoa.

Answer (score 2):

It will update the icon for the user's when it's distributed. I had an app i released to the app store that I had gotten from Google Images and made into an icon. Long story short, I had to change my icon so it didn't look like another App's which had the same icon! If you change it in your Build Settings you'll be ok.

If you change your apple-touch-icon.png for both regular and retina in your Build Settings, it will update on the app store, and the end user's ultimately. Bottom line. It should've did it for yours, I don't know why it didn't?

Comment: Thanks. As for review swapping, I'm not sure it's SO-community kosher, but I'll check it out and if we have to remove such comments, we can. Here's mine: http://www.skudio.com/colorfrenzy/

Comment: lol, i'd say it's a trade off, if moderator sees this, apologies.

Comment: that is pretty cool bro, just clicked the link! if a moderator sees that, i'm sure its not too bad. There are worse things, than plugging your app, i'm sure.

Comment: i like the translucent buttons!